# Creating a Turing machine for Substring and Equal String

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, computation-models, substrings

How should I go about creating a single-tape Turing machine for the following language:

$$
x_{1,2} = \bigl\{ (a\#b) \mid (a,b) \in \{0,1\}^* \text{and a is a substring of b or a is equal to b}  \bigl\}
$$

Some strings that should be accepted are:

- 10#11011
- 1101#1011010101
- 000#1001011000
- 111#111

Some strings that shouldn't be accepted are:

- 000#11011
- 11#0001
- 

I have a slight idea that the Turing machine should first check for the `#` symbol, and reject if the separator isn't found. Then start comparing both strings and if a symbol matches replace it with X. However, I would appreciate help on the exact states and transitions required to implement this machine.